# Return ResultSet from update statement?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, resultset, jtds

I tried to return the id of the affected row I updated. I am wondering, why I don't get a ResultSet back from this (only primary key would be ok), eventhough I set `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`? I connect to a Microsoft SQL Server using the most recent jTDS driver 1.3.0.

```
    try
    {
        PreparedStatement pst = SQL.getConnection().prepareStatement(qry, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

        pst.setString(1, someValue);
        pst.setString(2, someOtherValue);

        int affectedRows = pst.executeUpdate(); 
        System.out.println(affectedRows); //to make sure whether the query updated anything

        ResultSet rs = pst.getGeneratedKeys();

        if (rs.next())
        {
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStacktTrace();
    }
```

Any suggestions here?

Comment: What is the query? What keys are being generated?

Comment: is the key whihc you are trying to retrieve an auto increment column??

Comment: Which is the error? `rs` null? No `rs.next()`? `rs.getInt(1)` fails? Please be more specific if you want any meaningful aid.

Comment: @SJuan76: when come to the statement `if (rs.next())` it jumps over.. no error, just a seem to be empty ResultSet.

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR: yes it is, but it doesn't even come that far..

Comment: @Thilo: The query is a simple update query like `INSERT INTO tbl_Temp (?, ?) VALUES (?, ?)`. For testing purposes I just made it simple by creating a table with 3 rows, where as 1 of them is the primary key (ID).

Comment: @Polppan: your provided solution did not work because it takes GENERATED_KEY as a column name, which obviously does not exist. It seems like I don't get a row in my ResultSet at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JDBC How to get all generated keys from single insert with many values query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44526838/jdbc-how-to-get-all-generated-keys-from-single-insert-with-many-values-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround is to create a stored procedure and call it by using the CallableStatement method. Don't ask me why this works and not the other way though.

Comment: I am using a CallableStatement to call a stored procedure using `callableStatement.executeUpdate()` but I am still getting this error.
I am calling multiple stored procedures from the same place with a loop. But this issue is occurring for only one stored procedure.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

With SQL Server 2008 and later you can use an [OUTPUT clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) in your INSERT or UPDATE statement. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44553298/2144390) for an example.