# JDBC How to get all generated keys from single insert with many values query?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, insert, jtds

I'm inserting multiple rows using a PreparedStatement with a single query:

```
String query = "insert into MyTable (a,b,c) values (?,?,?),(?,?,?),(?,?,?),(?,?,?)"; // insert 4 rows in a single query
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
// .. here: loop to set all 4 x 3 values in my prepared statement
```

And I want to get the IDs generated by the MSSQL DB. I'm not sure which flavor of `execute` to use.

The `execute()` method doesn't return the expected `ResultSet`:

```
boolean thingy = stmt.execute();
System.out.println("execute returned ", thingy); // false: meaning no result set
ResultSet result = stmt.getResultSet(); // result is null
```

The `executeUpdate()` method returns only one `ResultSet`:

```
int rowCount = stmt.executeUpdate();
System.out.println(rowCount + " rows updated"); // 4 rows updated
ResultSet result = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
// there's only one result:
result.next(); // true
int ID1 = result.getInt(1); // good
result.next(); // false, no more rows
```

Is it possible to get the generated IDs with a single INSERT? I do not want to send multiple INSERT queries for performance reasons.

DB: MS SQL Server 11 (2012)
URL: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://...
Driver: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver jtds version 1.3.1

Comment: Which DBMS are JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: updated post with driver info

Comment: The jTDS driver is pretty outdated. Does it work with the Microsoft Driver?

Comment: Good point, horse, I'll check that...

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server 2008 and later, adding an [OUTPUT clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) to the INSERT statement seems to do the trick:

```java
try (Statement st = conn.createStatement()) {
    // TEST ENVIRONMENT: in a real application, this would be our permanent table
    st.execute("CREATE TABLE #tmp (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, txtcol NVARCHAR(50))");
    st.execute("INSERT INTO #tmp (txtcol) VALUES (N'existing data')");
    st.execute("INSERT INTO #tmp (txtcol) VALUES (N'more existing data')");
}
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("INSERT INTO #tmp (txtcol) ");
sb.append("    OUTPUT INSERTED.id ");
sb.append("    VALUES (?), (?), (?) ");
try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sb.toString())) {
    ps.setString(1, "foo");
    ps.setString(2, "bar");
    ps.setString(3, "baz");
    try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
        }
    }
}
```

which produces

```
3
4
5
```

Comment: This looks promising (using this successfully in Javascript), but with Java, I get "`java.sql.SQLException: The target table 'MyTable' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause.`"

Comment: I think I need to create a temporary table to put the output into.

Comment: re: *"a temporary table to put the output into"* - That's essentially what happens in the anonymous code block of the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing this answer, neither jTDS nor mssql-jdbc support returning of multiple generated keys using `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`, either from an INSERT statement with a TVC (table value constructor) or by using `executeBatch` with a `PreparedStatement`. However, the following code works with both drivers (tested with jTDS 1.3.1 and [the dev branch of mssql-jdbc](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/tree/dev) at the time of writing):

```java
try (Statement st = conn.createStatement()) {
    // TEST ENVIRONMENT: in a real application, this would be our permanent table
    st.execute("CREATE TABLE #tmp (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, txtcol NVARCHAR(50))");
    st.execute("INSERT INTO #tmp (txtcol) VALUES (N'existing data')");
    st.execute("INSERT INTO #tmp (txtcol) VALUES (N'more existing data')");
}
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("SET NOCOUNT ON; ");
sb.append("DECLARE @seq INT, @txt NVARCHAR(50), @id INT; ");
sb.append("DECLARE @newIds TABLE (seq INT, id INT); ");
sb.append("DECLARE @toInsert TABLE (seq INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, txt NVARCHAR(50)); ");
sb.append("");
sb.append("INSERT INTO @toInsert (txt) VALUES (?), (?), (?); ");
sb.append("");
sb.append("DECLARE crsr CURSOR FOR SELECT seq, txt FROM @toInsert ORDER BY seq; ");
sb.append("OPEN crsr; ");
sb.append("FETCH NEXT FROM crsr INTO @seq, @txt; ");
sb.append("WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 ");
sb.append("BEGIN ");
sb.append("    INSERT INTO #tmp (txtcol) VALUES (@txt); ");
sb.append("    SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY(); ");
sb.append("    INSERT INTO @newIds (seq, id) VALUES (@seq, @id); ");
sb.append("    FETCH NEXT FROM crsr INTO @seq, @txt; ");
sb.append("END ");
sb.append("SELECT id FROM @newIds ORDER BY seq; ");
try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sb.toString())) {
    ps.setString(1, "foo");
    ps.setString(2, "bar");
    ps.setString(3, "baz");
    try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
        }
    }
}
```

which produces

```
3
4
5
```